# Issue while building eclipse che project using "mvn clean install" command

Tags: maven, eclipse-che

**I am using online IDE of eclipse che.
Below is the issue that i am facing while trying to build the project:-**

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.eclipse.che:che-bookmark-plugin-parent:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not transfer artifact org.eclipse.che.depmgt:maven-depmgt-pom:pom:5.0.0-M5-SNAPSHOT from/to codenvy-public-repo (https://maven.codenvycorp.com/content/groups/public/): 
Transfer failed for https://maven.codenvycorp.com/content/groups/public/org/eclipse/che/depmgt/maven-depmgt-pom/5.0.0-M5-SNAPSHOT/maven-depmgt-pom-5.0.0-M5-SNAPSHOT.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 16, column 13
```

**You can get the Code used at** :- https://github.com/vzhukovskii/che-bookmark-plugin

Comment: Looks like a network issue: `Transfer failed for...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project is very old and it seems that example has been made for Che 6 (or even Che 5).
The error you are facing is probably because it's trying to download the (again very old) maven artifact from maven.codenvycorp.com, which no longer exists.
If you write down what you are trying to achieve (I believe building some obsolete plugin for obsolete version of Che is not your goal) we might be able to help you ;-)

If you want some "bookmark" plugin in some recent version of Che (7.x), I suggest you to take a look for some vscode extension which would solve your needs, as Che 7.x (Theia in particular, which is the default editor for Che) should be able to use that vscode extension.

Comment: Thank you. What I need is to create a custom view in eclipse Che. Can anyone please suggest some examples or useful links?